# Best practice - JSON vs JS Object

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Consider this [simple angular example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/brljyjexkdld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form-question.component.ts) & navigate to `question.service.ts`

Snippet from question.service.ts:

```
new DropdownQuestion({
        key: 'brave',
        label: 'Bravery Rating',
        options: [
          {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
          {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
          {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
          {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
        ],
        order: 3
      })
```

Alternate to above (raw json):

```
{
       key: 'brave',
        label: 'Bravery Rating',
        options: [
          {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
          {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
          {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
          {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
        ],
        order: 3
      }
```

What I feel is rather than passing this raw json (as described above), I use the method 1 described above.

I don't have enough arguments to support my point here. But I feel that passing in JS object using the supplied JSON object as parameter is way better than passing raw json, in terms or readability, maintainability & OOP.

I am facing a hard time convincing my fellow colleagues to agree with my approach. What would actually be the best way here? Is passing raw json really a better approach then JS? or vice versa? Is there any alternate way to this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: neither of the things you've shown is valid JSON - paste them into https://jsonlint.com/ and you'll see. They're both valid as JavaScript objects though. JSON is a textual representation of an object, usually used for transferring data (e.g. in a HTTP request) or sometimes for storing it (e.g. in a file or a NoSQL database or something). As such it's quite unclear what point you're trying to make.

Comment: This will probably get closed because it is opinion based. Is there any logic that goes along with your `DropdownQuestion` class? If not, there is no need to have a class for that, but you should still create an interface with the same signature so that you can have the proper type safety. Without functions, the objects will be equivalent from a JS object perspective.

Comment: I don't get your point? If you talk about `raw JSON` do you mean a js object? and how is the first more readable than the second?

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, both of them are completely irrelevant since first option expecting some specific format as `input` however second option is free data structure which can be feed as `input` to `DropdownQuestion`.
- Second, I am guessing, what you are seeking for is to force the control to have very specific structure rather than wrapping something in it. You `DropdownQuestion` class should be look like as  -

  ```
   class DropdownQuestion implements Control{

      public key;
      public label;
      public order;
      public options =[];

   }
  ```

Here `Control` is common interface that needs to be implemented by all `Controls`.

Comment: there's no such thing as a "json object" in the way you're implying. It's a _JavaScript_ object. JSON is text. "Raw JSON" and "JSON" are the same thing.

Comment: Its point one is creating confusion, I was talking about in different sense. Anyway I erased that point to avoid confusion.